# want current date and time in "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS" format

Tags: java

I am using following code to get date in "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS" format.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTime{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
        String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current date in String Format: "+strDate);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf1.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
        Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println("Current date in Date Format: "+date);
    }
}
```

And I am getting following output

```
Current date in String Format: 05/01/2012 21:10:17.287
Current date in Date Format: Thu Jan 05 21:10:17 IST 2012
```

Kindly suggest what I should do to display the date in same string format(dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS) i.e i want following output:

```
Current date in String Format: 05/01/2012 21:10:17.287
Current date in Date Format: 05/01/2012 21:10:17.287
```

Comment: when you System.out.println a date object, the Date's toString Method is called. You would need to create your own subclass of Date and overwrite the toString method to output the Date the way you want it to.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want, but understand this: `Date.toString()` returns the default format, nothing can be done about it. You have to use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the string output.

Comment: Do you mean `.SSS` for milli-seconds? Java doesn't support 1/100ths of a second. If you use `.SS` it many not behave as you expect.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 19):

SimpleDateFormat

```
sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
String dateString=sdf.format(date);
```

It will give the output `28/09/2013 09:57:19` as you expected.

[For complete program click here](http://java-interview-questions.com/how-to-display-date-in-ddmmyyyy-hhmmss-format-in-java/)

Comment: java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(ackDateTimeString); worked for me finally !

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 15):

You can't - because you're calling `Date.toString()` which will *always* include the system time zone if that's in the default date format for the default locale. The `Date` value itself has no concept of a format. If you want to format it in a particular way, use `SimpleDateFormat.format()`... using `Date.toString()` is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 12):

The following code gives expected output. Is that what you want?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
        String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current date in String Format: " + strDate);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf1.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
        Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);
        String string = sdf1.format(date);
        System.out.println("Current date in Date Format: " + string);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

- Use modern *java.time* classes.
- Never use `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes.

Example:

```
ZonedDateTime                                // Represent a moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
.now(                                        // Capture the current moment.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )              // Always specify time zone using proper `Continent/Region` format. Never use 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as EST, PDT, IST, etc.
)
.truncatedTo(                                // Lop off finer part of this value.
    ChronoUnit.MILLIS                        // Specify level of truncation via `ChronoUnit` enum object.
)                                            // Returns another separate `ZonedDateTime` object, per immutable objects pattern, rather than alter (“mutate”) the original.
.format(                                     // Generate a `String` object with text representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME    // This standard ISO 8601 format is close to your desired output.
)                                            // Returns a `String`.
.replace( "T" , " " )                        // Replace `T` in middle with a SPACE.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible old date-time classes such as `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`.

> want current date and time

Capture the current moment in UTC using `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To view that same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Or, as a shortcut, pass a `ZoneId` to the `ZonedDateTime.now` method.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes use a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That means up to nine digits of a decimal fraction of a second. If you want only three, milliseconds, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)). Pass your desired limit as a [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum object.

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
)
.truncatedTo(
    ChronoUnit.MILLIS
)
```

> in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format

I recommend always including the offset-from-UTC or time zone when generating a string, to avoid ambiguity and misunderstanding.

But if you insist, you can specify a specific format when generating a string to represent your date-time value. A built-in pre-defined formatter nearly meets your desired format, but for a `T` where you want a SPACE.

```
String output = 
    zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
    .replace( "T" , " " )  
;
```

> sdf1.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
>
> Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);

Never exchange date-time values using text intended for presentation to humans.

Instead, use the standard formats defined for this very purpose, found in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The *java.time* use these ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Always include an indicator of the offset-from-UTC or time zone when exchanging a specific moment. So your desired format discussed above is to be avoided for data-exchange. Furthermore, generally best to exchange a moment as UTC. This means an `Instant` in *java.time*. You can exchange a `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime`, effectively adjusting from a time zone to UTC for the same moment, same point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
String exchangeThisString = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z

This ISO 8601 format uses a `Z` on the end to represent UTC, pronounced “Zulu”.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date back to the format that you are looking for.

```
System.out.println("Current date in Date Format: " + sdf.format(date));
```

**Update 2023**: As pointed in other answers, code nowadays should default to [Java Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html), including `SimpleDateFormat` modern, immutable and thread-safe cousin: [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple snippet working in Java 8 and using the "new" date and time API LocalDateTime:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
```

Answer (score 1):

The output in your first printline is using your formatter. The output in your second (the date created from your parsed string) is output using Date#toString which formats according to its own rules. That is, you're not using a formatter.

The rules are as per what you're seeing and described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answer does *not* endorse the use of the `Date` class (in fact it’s long outdated and poorly designed, so I’d rather discourage it completely). I try to answer a regularly recurring question about date and time objects with a format. For this purpose I am using the `Date` class as example. Other classes are treated at the end.

### You don’t want to

You don’t want a `Date` with a specific format. Good practice in all but the simplest throw-away programs is to keep your user interface apart from your model and your business logic. The value of the `Date` object belongs in your model, so keep your `Date` there and never let the user see it directly. When you adhere to this, it will never matter which format the `Date` has got. Whenever the user should see the date, format it into a `String` and show the string to the user. Similarly if you need a specific format for persistence or exchange with another system, format the `Date` into a string for that purpose. If the user needs to enter a date and/or time, either accept a string or use a date picker or time picker.

Special case: storing into an SQL database. It may appear that your database requires a specific format. Not so. Use `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(yourParamIndex, yourDateOrTimeObject)` where `yourDateOrTimeObject` is a `LocalDate`,  `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` or an instance of an appropriate date-time class from java.time. And again don’t worry about the format of that object. Search for more details.

### You cannot

A `Date` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. It’s a point in time, nothing more, nothing less. A container of a value. In your code `sdf1.parse` *converts*  your string into a `Date` object, that is, into a point in time. It doesn’t keep the string nor the format that was in the string.

To finish the story, let’s look at the next line from your code too:

```
    System.out.println("Current date in Date Format: "+date);
```

In order to perform the string concatenation required by the `+` sign Java needs to convert your `Date` into a `String` first. It does this by calling the `toString` method of your `Date` object. `Date.toString` always produces a string like `Thu Jan 05 21:10:17 IST 2012`. There is no way you could change that (except in a subclass of `Date`, but you don’t want that). Then the generated string is concatenated with the string literal to produce the string printed by `System.out.println`.

In short “format” applies only to the string representations of dates, not to the dates themselves.

### Isn’t it strange that a Date hasn’t got a format?

I think what I’ve written is quite as we should expect. It’s similar to other types. Think of an `int`. The same `int` may be formatted into strings like `53,551`, `53.551` (with a dot as thousands separator), `00053551`, `+53 551` or even `0x0000_D12F`. All of this formatting produces strings, while the `int` just stays the same and doesn’t change its format. With a `Date` object it’s exactly the same: you can format it into many different strings, but the `Date` itself always stays the same.

### Can I then have a LocalDate, a ZonedDateTime, a Calendar, a GregorianCalendar, an XMLGregorianCalendar, a java.sql.Date, Time or Timestamp in the format of my choice?

No, you cannot, and for the same reasons as above. None of the mentioned classes, in fact no date or time class I have ever met, can have a format. You can have your desired format only in a `String` outside your date-time object.

### Links

- [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) on Wikipedia
- [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s coding blog
- Answers by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303885/5772882) and [Pitto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113564/5772882) explaining what to do instead (also using classes that are more modern and far more programmer friendly than `Date`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAVA8 API then this code will help.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateTimeString = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
System.out.println(dateTimeString);
```

It will print the date in the given format.

But if you again create a object of LocalDateTime it will print the 'T' in between the date and time.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

So as mentioned in earlier posts as well, the representation and usage is different.

Its better to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" pattern and convert the string/date object accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Date date = new Date();
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
```

intead Of

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTime{

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
     Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
     DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS", 
      Locale.ENGLISH);
    String strDate = format.format(date);
    System.out.println("Current date in String Format: "+strDate);
   }
}
```

use this code u will get current date in expected string format