# Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, converters

How to convert calendar date to `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date date = cal.getTime();             
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date1 = format1.format(date);            
Date inActiveDate = null;
try {
    inActiveDate = format1.parse(date1);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will produce `inActiveDate = Wed Sep 26 00:00:00 IST 2012`. But what I need is `2012-09-26`. My purpose is to compare this date with another date in my database using Hibernate criteria. So I need the date object in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: You're code is confusing.  Are you trying to format a `Date` to `yyyy-MM-dd` or parse a String from `yyyy-MM-dd` to a `Date` value??  To format the date, simply use `format1.format(date)`, to parse it, use `format1.parse(someStringValueInTheCorrectFormat)`

Comment: I have edited my question.. Sorry for the previous mistake..

Comment: one liner: `( new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" ) ).format( Calendar.getInstance().getTime() );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format)

Comment: @IwanAucamp: you are creating a **new** instance on *every* call — this is wasteful because the formatter can be a constant and can only be created once (given that you don't need thread safety as SDF is not thread-safe).

Answer (score 379, accepted):

A Java `Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

When you use something like `System.out.println(date)`, Java uses `Date.toString()` to print the contents.

The only way to change it is to override `Date` and provide your own implementation of `Date.toString()`.  Now before you fire up your IDE and try this, I wouldn't; it will only complicate matters. You are better off formatting the date to the format you want to use (or display).

## Java 8+

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
DateTimeFormatter formmat1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(ldt);
// Output "2018-05-12T17:21:53.658"

String formatter = formmat1.format(ldt);
System.out.println(formatter);
// 2018-05-12
```

## Prior to Java 8

You should be making use of the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

The following is maintained for historical purposes (as the original answer)

What you can do, is format the date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
// Output "Wed Sep 26 14:23:28 EST 2012"

String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(formatted);
// Output "2012-09-26"

System.out.println(format1.parse(formatted));
// Output "Wed Sep 26 00:00:00 EST 2012"
```

These are actually the same date, represented differently.

Comment: Is it possible to get tomorrows date without using calendar class?

Comment: Kind of, but it's much easier with `Calendar`

Comment: Anyway to remove timezone completely from from this calender object?

Comment: No, not really, you could try creating a Calendar with a GMT time zone (0 millisecond offset) using something like `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`

Comment: If you're really serious about date/time manipulation, take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), it's significantly easier then messing around with `Calendar`

Comment: I want to point out that this code is wrong in general - its output depends on what timezone of the machine it is running on. Very often, that time zone happens to be the same time zone as the DB dates. But sometimes, they're not the same. A date like 2012-09-09 is ambiguous if you don't define the time zone. A timestamp is absolute. Anyway if you do cal.add, it's using the system time zone - may or may not be correct but is certainly not good code.

Comment: @n13 if the question was about database date manipulation or even time manipulation I might agree with you. The question was how to represent a date value in particular date format

Comment: @IwanAucamp one liners aren't always practical, especially when trying to explain a concept. You may want to reuse the formatter for example, they can also be difficult to read, for example

Comment: Nicely structured answer - this is basically Model(Date)-View(Format) separation.

Comment: Could anyone please explain why this answer would deserve a downvote? "It's not using the new shiny Java 8 API" -  It was 2012 for crying out loud

Comment: I love the idea that this should draw a downvote - can someone please explain how this is not answering the OPs question or how it could be done better?!

Answer (score 22):

Your code is wrong. No point of  parsing date and keep that as Date object.

You can format the calender date object when you want to display and keep  that as a string.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date date = cal.getTime();             
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");          
String inActiveDate = null;
try {
    inActiveDate = format1.format(date);
    System.out.println(inActiveDate );
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

## java.time

The [answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576219/642706) is correct, especially the tip about [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). The successor to Joda-Time is now built into [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) as the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html). Here's example code in Java 8.

When working with date-time (as opposed to local date), the [**time zone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) in critical. The day-of-month depends on the time zone. For example, the [India time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India) is `+05:30` (five and a half hours ahead of UTC), while [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_France) is only one hour ahead. So a moment in a new day in India has one date while the same moment in France has “yesterday’s” date. Creating string output lacking any time zone or offset information is creating ambiguity. You asked for YYYY-MM-DD output so I provided, but I don't recommend it. Instead of [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) I would have used [`ISO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE) to get this output: `2014-02-25+05:30`

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );

DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE; // Caution: The "LOCAL" part means we are losing time zone information, creating ambiguity.
String output = formatterOutput.format( zonedDateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "zonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
zonedDateTime: 2014-02-25T14:22:20.919+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
output: 2014-02-25
```

## Joda-Time

Similar code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, the precursor to java.time.

```
DateTimeZone zone = new DateTimeZone( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

## ISO 8601

By the way, that format of your input string is a standard format, one of several handy date-time string formats defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating string representations of various date-time values.

Answer (score 6):

`java.util.Date` object can't represent *date* in *custom* format instead you've to use `SimpleDateFormat.format` method that returns `string`.

```
String myString=format1.format(date);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, date);
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
    String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(formatted);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context/explanation, as code only answers do not fulfill our standards. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to parse a `java.util.Date` object you have to convert it to String first using your own format.

```
inActiveDate = format1.parse(  format1.format(date)  );
```

But I believe you are being redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
Date date = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ft.format(date));
```

This will display your date + 7 days in month, day and year format in a JOption window pane.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String ThisWeekStartDate(WebDriver driver) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //ensure the method works within current month
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        System.out.println("Before Start Date " + c.getTime());
        Date date = c.getTime();

          SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh.mm a");

          String CurrentDate = dfDate.format(date);
          System.out.println("Start Date " + CurrentDate);
          return CurrentDate;

    }
    public static String ThisWeekEndDate(WebDriver driver) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //ensure the method works within current month
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        System.out.println("Before End Date " + c.getTime());
        Date date = c.getTime();

          SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh.mm a");

          String CurrentDate = dfDate.format(date);
          System.out.println("End Date " + CurrentDate);
          return CurrentDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is for kotlin language.

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to achieve the result:

```
val date = Date(timeInSec)
val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale("IN")).format(date)
```

for details click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72613055/14004940).

**OR**

Use `Calendar` to do it for you:

```
val dateObject = Date(timeInMillis)
val calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance()
calendarInstance.time = dateObject
val date = "${calendarInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR)}-${calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH)}-${calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DATE)}"
```

For more details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72607027/14004940).

Comment: I know that `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` were asked about, but that was in 2012, and surely no one needs them in 2022 since they are poorly designed and their replacement, java.time, came out more than 8 years ago.

Comment: @OleV.V. I disagree with "not needed". If it is still in existence there must be need. Anyway thanks for mentioning java.time package.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code where date is compared in a format to compare with date field in database...may be this might be helpful to you...

When you convert the string to date using simpledateformat, it is hard to compare with the Date field in mysql databases.

So convert the java string date in the format using select STR_to_DATE('yourdate','%m/%d/%Y') --> in this format, then you will get the exact date format of mysql date field.

http://javainfinite.com/java/java-convert-string-to-date-and-compare/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow because of link-rot and other issues. Can you give a summary of the information with key points?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about y'all, but I always want this stuff as a one-liner. The other answers are fine and dandy and work great, but here is it condensed to a single line. Now you can hold less lines of code in your mind :-).

Here is the one Liner:

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). A java.time one-liner is `String currentDate = LocalDate.now().toString();`. Shorter than yours. :-)

Comment: Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on the terribly flawed legacy classes when they adopted JSR 310 defining the *java.time* classes. I suggest you do the same.