# Java program : need current Date in YYYY-MM-DD format without time in Date datatype

Tags: java, date-formatting

I need Date with only yyyy-mm-dd format, because DB2 table having 10 precision of date column.

Comment: You need to read the docs.  [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...Wouldn't the JDBC driver be capable of converting this value for?  Something like [PreparedStatement#setDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java)

Comment: Tried this but giving date with Time

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
String modifiedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
```

This will do.

Comment: I have tried this but when i will put this string in Date() then it is return time stamp with 00:00:00, and then my insert statement failed because of validation of 10 precision

Comment: why you need to do that? You just need yyyy-mm-dd right?You can not change the date object dear.

Comment: No, My bean have Date data type, so that i need to convert it to Date()

Comment: maybe you have a java.util.Date and need to convert it to java.sql.Date ?

Comment: Bean having java.util.Date

Comment: Change you bean variable to String. I guess this is only for displaying the date