# How to get Date from Calender object in Android.?

Tags: java, android

I have Calender object as follows--

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and I want to get/extract date from above Calendar object in the following format--

```
"Sat Jul 20 14:53:36 GMT+02:00 2013"
```

Can anybody please tell me How can I do this..!!

Comment: What have you tried? [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html), Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the calendars data `set()`, `add()`, and `roll()`.
2. Use the Calendars [`getTime()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) to get a `Date`-object.
3. Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date like you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String dat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy").format(calendar.getTime())
    System.out.println(dat);//"Sat Jul 20 14:53:36 GMT+02:00 2013"
```

Should work for you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
   call getTime() by using Calendar reference

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    tv.setText(calendar.getTime() + "");

     **or**

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
tv.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```