# Changing Date type and format

Tags: java, date

I have the below method in which date is coming as parameter that is in form of string and that parameter name is `dateString` as shown below and ultimately the date is converted and stored n form of `java.sql.Date` which is also return type of this method.

```
public static java.sql.Date getSimpleDate11(String dateString) {

        if (dateString == null) {
            return null;
        }
        java.util.Date date = null;
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;

        try {

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            df.setLenient(false);
            date = df.parse(dateString);
            sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        } catch (Exception pe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "The date entered is invalid or has incorrect format"
                            + dateString);
        }
        return sqlDate;
    }
```

### Question:

I found that value is coming in this format 2014-07-23 (YYYY-MM-dd) and I want the return date (`java.sql..Date`) to be in 23-07-14 (dd-MM-YY).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java)

Comment: `Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT - the format is irrlevent

Comment: @MadProgrammer Request you to please advise and show if possible how can I cahenge the format from YYYY-MM-dd to dd-MM-YY format , please advise

Comment: i thnk the section in whih it shows that question ia already ansered is different

Comment: You can't - that's the answer, the format of `Date` is based on local.  `DateFormatter`'s are used to take a `Date` format and format them to some `String` value. `Date` is juts a container for the number of milliseconds since the epoch - it has no concept of format, it can't be changed and shouldn't be changed

Comment: *"i thnk the section in whih it shows that question ia already ansered is different"* - I think you're missing the point.  You're trying to change the way `Date#toString` prints the `Date` format, you can't as the linked answer explains.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks Request you to please adise then how can I achieve this , request you to please advise if possible can you please advise what changes I need to do in the code that I posted above.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't need to.  If the column in the database is some form of `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, then the JDBC driver should accept the `java.sql.Date` as is and will, as required, parse the value to and from the database.  If the column is some other type, then using something like `SimpleDateFormat` to produce the format you want is the correct process, but you won't be able to use `java.sql.Date` - the format should be irrelevant, its the concept of "time" that's important

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok agreed then is there any alternative then to achieve this thing , any alternative as I am stuck up now

Answer (score 0):

This generates the date format you want - just use `String` as the return type instead of `java.sql.Date`:

```
public static String getSimpleDate11(String dateString) {
    if (dateString == null) {
        return null;
    }

    DateFormat dfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateFormat dfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

    try {
        Date date = dfIn.parse(dateString);
        return dfOut.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "The date entered is invalid or has incorrect format"
                        + dateString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but at last I have to store the same format in java.sql.date please advise how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to convert the incoming "yyyy-MM-dd" `String` date to a `java.sql.Date` object you already did everything right in the code you posted in your question.

A `java.sql.Date` object, just like a `java.util.Date`, stores the date you give it internally in some format you, as a programmer, don't have to care about. You just have to know that the date is stored in the object and that you can get it out of the object whenever you need it. If you're interested in technical details you can google for it but, as I said, in your case this doesn't matter.

Whenever you need a `java.util.Date` object just use the one you get out of your original `getSimpleDate11(...)` function. Whenever you need a `String` representation of the date in a certain format, like "dd-MM-yy", take the `java.util.Date` and plug it into a DateFormat object initialized with the output format you want, just like I did in my first answer with `DateFormat dfOut` (the `format(...)` method of `DateFormat` can handle both, `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` objects).