# Get formatted date object from Calendar object

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have this code

```
String date = "18/06/2014";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));

c.add(Calendar.DATE, +2);
```

I'm trying to get formatted date object from calendar object but without any success. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `sdf.format(c.getTime())` will give you a formatted `String` of your date.

Comment: A date does not have a format.

Comment: but sdf.format should return a string value, right?

Comment: @GriffeyDog I need directly a formatted date object

Comment: `c.getTime()` gives you a `Date` object. There is no formatting associated with a `Date` object.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "formatted `Date` object".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` is an object, it doesn't have an inherent textual representation. The `SimpleDateFormat` class can be used to provide the textual representation you're looking for,

```
String date = "30/06/2014";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, +2);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Will output

```
02/07/2014
```

Comment: ok now I understand...the format is associated to the string and not to a date object

Comment: Actually it's associated to the formatter (in this case `sdf`), which produces the formatted `String` from the `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

> Date date = sdf.parse(date);