# How to pass correct time format trough Axis generated stub

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, axis

I have generated client stub using Apache Axis1, and according to the given XML request sample I should send the date in yyyy-MM-dd format. But axis generated stub has Calendar type for the setDate method.

eg :

setDate(Calendar date)

So when I pass the date, it is going like bellow,
2014-09-21T18:30:00.000Z

Which is not the correct format. How can I pass the correct date format here using the client stub ?

Does this need to change from web service side ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java

Check this link. This should answer your question

Comment: @Himanshu.MarJAVA Thank you for your link, but it is not what I looking for. Here issue is Axis generated method is having type as the Calendar  "setDate(Calendar date)". So even we format the date, we have to set a Calendar type object.