# Dateformat give different time in long

Tags: java, jodatime, simpledateformat

I have two date format one in string **"yyyy-MM-dd't'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"** and second one in long **"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"**.
I want to convert it into this format **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**, its convert successfully but when I print date.getTime() than

for first -> **1416490009109**

for second ->  **20141120121211800**

code:

```
private DateTimeFormatter formater,formater1;
private SimpleDateFormat formate,formate1,formate2;

String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
String pattern1 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";
//String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
formate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
formate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
formater = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
formater1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern1);

String dateTime = "2011-11-20'T'11:42:12.672+00:00";
long savePoint = 20141120114212672L;

try {
    datetime = formater.parseDateTime(dateTime);
    date = datetime.toDate();
    //Log.d("Android: ", "Date  formate: "+datetime);
    dt = formate.format(date.getTime());
    Log.d("Android: ", "date Keys1:   "+date.getTime());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Android: ", "Error: "+e);
}
```

for second one

```
try {
    String[] tzone = dateTime.split("[+]");
    String times = formate1.format(Long.parseLong(savePoint));
    datetime = formater.parseDateTime(times+"+"+tzone[tzone.length-1]);
    date = datetime.toDate();
    dt = formate.format(date.getTime());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Android:", "Error:  "+e);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code! what you have done so far?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve if conversion was successful? and what is wrong exactly? be specific!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java/12576219#12576219), *"A Java Date is a container for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"* it has no concept for format.  Use a `DateFormat` to display it in what ever format you want...

Comment: I am already using it but same date give different timestamp why

Comment: `dt = formate.format(date.getTime());` can be `dt = formate.format(date);`.  Using `date.getTime()` simply prints out it's number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, try using `dt` instead...

Comment: actualy my purpose is to sorting with date so i am using date.getTime()

Comment: why do you have a "T" between date and time????

Comment: @Joseph118 That `T` in the middle is part of one of the several useful date-time string formats defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard is used as a default by both the Joda-Time library and java.time package for parsing and generating strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Count from epoch

The first input appears to be a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

Parse the string into a `long` using [`Integer.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)).

```
long count = Long.parseLong( "1416490009109" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( count ) ;
```

For more flexibility such as generating text in various formats, convert to `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) :
```

## String as integer

Your second input appears to be a string of year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fractional second masquerading as a long integer.

```
String input = "20141120121211800" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSSS" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Assign a time zone or offset-from-UTC if known with certainty.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## Generating strings

> I want to convert it into this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

To produce text from your date-time object in your desired format, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use DateFormat to convert dates. This can help you out!

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(stringDate);
```

If you want to compare dates later on use

```
date1.after(date2)
```

or

```
date1.before(date2)
```

more about date can be found on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html