# p:calendar with datatype String in managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I'm working on a datatable in which a **single column** contains various fields like

- Name
- Salary
- Date
- Birth

So I took datatype as `String` in my bean for that column.

Now my concern is, can I use `p:calendar` for **date of birth** with datatype `String` in my bean?

If so then how?

Comment: the problem with String is : You can not expect the user input type information example User A : `10/11/2016` and User B : `11/10/2016`, User C  `Wed 13,11,2016` did you get the point

Comment: Sounds like a bad choice.. why not use real good types and take a different approach

Comment: @Kukeltje what different approach,could you please be more specific.I need some string fields like name and some date fields in the same column

Comment: That is next to impossible since I do not see the problem with using multiple different fields with different types in one colum.

Answer (score 1):

Use a FacesConverter

Proof of concept:

```
@Named
public class DateStringConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            return parser.parse(arg2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        return arg2.toString();
    }

}
```

xhthml

```
<p:calendar value="#{dateAsString}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" converter="#{dateStringConverter}" />
```

Comment: and how do you handle the case of `MM.DD.YYYY`

Comment: I don't understand. This isn't a valid pattern. Do you know the p:calendar component?

Comment: please read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java  and read my comment you will understand that if the date is in `String` user can input every/anything inside it

Comment: p:calendar validate the user input. I have changed my answer to a FacesConver.

Comment: @jklee i didn't get it..how can i use the facesConverter and after implementing it, will i be able to use p:calendar with datatype string in bean?