# LocalDate pattern that shows day as weekday

Tags: javafx, date-formatting, date-conversion, string-conversion, localdate

I search for a pattern which looks like this: `Thu, 11. 05. 1999` 
So I tried this syntax:

```
String pattern = "DDD, dd. mm. uuuu";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
```

But it won't work. When trying to format a `LocalDate` I get `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: MinuteOfHour`.

Comment: may be this can help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java

I prefer SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: @bmavus You prefer `SimpleDateFormat`? That class has proven troublesome for years (see how many questions about unexpected `SImpleDateFormat` behaviour there are on Stack Overflow). And it’s long outdated. IMHO the OP is doing very well in using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. We all should. Also your link doesn’t seem to explain how to get weekday, as the question title asks.

Comment: LolIPop65, next time plesae be specific about how your code doesn’t work. Specify precisely how the observed outcome is different from the expected. In many situations it will give us a much better basis for helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look into the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of Java explaining the format pattern syntax is always good:

- E = day-of-week
- M = month
- m = minute

So you should try this pattern:

```
EEE, dd. MM. uuuu
```

And setting the locale explicitly to English is also a good idea.

Comment: Nice answer. Upvoted for the recommendation of using an explicit locale.