# add or sub in Date using calender

Tags: java, date

I want to remove the time from dateAndTime, and also want to have all of them in numeric form like this: 10-10-2019

> output: Wed Nov 10 16:39:58 AST 2010

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    //Java calendar in default timezone and default locale
    int day =10;
    int month =10;
    int year =10;

Calendar m =  Calendar.getInstance();  
 m.set(year, month, day);
  m.add(day, 10);
 System.out.println(" Date :" + m.getTime());
```

Comment: Instead of calendar use Java time api instead

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Then use a `DateTimeFormatter` to obtain the output format you want.

Comment: When you ask for `10-10-2019`, should that be month-day-year or day-month-year? Also should September 1 be 1-9-2019 or 01-09-2019? You can have it the way you want.

Comment: `LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 30).plusDays(10).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"))` gives `10-10-2019`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SimpleDateFormat` for early versions of java or `DateTimeFormatter` for java8+.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //java8+
        //recommended
        String formattedToday = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-YYYY").format(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(formattedToday);

        //early versions of java
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY").format(today.getTime());
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }

}
```

output:

```
09-18-2019
09-18-2019
```

Also read [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576219/432903)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). There's a lot of [example](https://alvinalexander.com/java/simpledateformat-convert-date-to-string-formatted-parse) you can use.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.