# Get the Start date and End date of a Selected month from a Combo box using current year in Java 7

Tags: javafx, java-7

I want to get Start date and End date of a Month when a month select from a combo box.
The combo box is filled with months like January, February..... when i select a month in combo box, i want to get the Start and End date of that month with current year.
but here in the below code, year is specified in a text box. but i want to get the current year. not from text box.
Please help me to solve this problem.
thanks for advance.

this is the code  i have tried

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cmbMonth.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
 int yearpart = Integer.parseInt(txtYear.getText());
 int monthPart = cmbMonth.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
 int dateDay = 1;
     cal.set(yearpart, monthPart, dateDay);
     int numOfDaysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     System.out.println("Number of Days: " + numOfDaysInMonth);
     System.out.println("First Day of month: " + cal.getTime());
     cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numOfDaysInMonth-1);
     System.out.println("Last Day of month: " + cal.getTime());
```

When I select month February in combo box . i want output like this

```
  First Day of month: 2019-02-1
  Last Day of month: 2019-02-28
```

Now i got this kind of output

```
First Day of month: Fri Feb 01 11:32:47 IST 2019
Last Day of month: Thur Feb 28 11:32:47 IST 2019
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java)

Comment: You only need a ```SimpleDateFormat``` if you're using **Java 8**. If you're using **Java 8+** you can use ```DateTimeFormatter```

Comment: @poisn  i am using java 7

Comment: ```SimpleDateFormat``` should be possible to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `YearMonth`:

```
int year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
String month = "January";
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(year, Month.valueOf(month.toUpperCase()));

System.out.println(LocalDate.of(yearMonth.getYear(), yearMonth.getMonth(), 1));
System.out.println(yearMonth.atEndOfMonth());
```

Comment: Does this work on Java 7? It does if you use the backport of java.time. [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).