# How can I store two digit month in Firebase using Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've now tried a couple of different methods to get the format I want in my Firebase Database:

I use the java.util.Calendar import in Android Studio.

Method 1:

```
if (endMonth <= 9) {
    endYear = endYear * 10;
    endDate = Integer.toString(endYear) + Integer.toString(endMonth) + Integer.toString(endDay);
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (endMonth <= 9) {
    endDate = Integer.toString(endYear * 10) + Integer.toString(endMonth) + Integer.toString(endDay);
}
```

Method 3:

```
if (endMonth <= 9) {
    endDate = Integer.toString(endYear) + "0" + Integer.toString(endMonth) + Integer.toString(endDay);
}
```

I have also tried to store methods 1 and 2 as integers. However, they all end up in the Firebase Database as "2022328" or equivalent, whereas I want it to store as "20220328".

Comment: Is the problem converting the string value locally before your store it? or the value looks fine on device but changes after your store it?

Comment: Have you tried to format the date?

Comment: @MehranB It happens before i store it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've tried to find a forum post describing how to format java.util.Calendar, but I've only found forum posts about java.util.date, which I unfortunately can't use for my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `SimpleDateFormat` for that.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String stringDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Also see:

- [Calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575990/calendar-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-java)

Comment: Thank You!
Your link helped out alot!!
Have a great weekend ^-^

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date using `SimpleDateFormatter`:

Using **Java**:

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime() // Today's date
String formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd",Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
```

Using **Kotlin**:

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance().time // Today's date
val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this work, when calculating the date the next day?
I'm not sure how to do it when using the Date.

Comment: @DJFeder It’s easy, but then you will need to switch to java.time as mentioned in my comment under the other answer. You may for instance define `LocalDate currentDay = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());` and then `LocalDate nextDay = currentDay.plusDays(1);`. The format you ask for is built in, so formatting goes like `String endDate = nextDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);`.