# Required Java Calendar with dd/mm/yyyy HH:ss:MM format

Tags: java

I need to **java.util.Calendar** object with dd/mm/yyyy HH:ss:MM format. Please help me. I am getting always below format.

Thu Nov 21 14:12:57 EST 2013.

I have need the dd/mm/yyyy HH:ss:MM format in calendar object while fetch the getTime() method.

Comment: Could you post the code which is producing the current output. Thanks

Comment: Follow this link of stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format?rq=1

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html read this first

Answer (score 0):

Refer below tutorial about Java Date, Calendar and Time API - Tutorial.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html