# Convert String "22/08/2013" to date format 2013/08/22

Tags: scala, date, date-format, simpledateformat

This is my code in scala

```
 var s:String ="22/08/2013"
 var  simpleDateFormat:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
 var  date:Date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
 println(date)
```

the date is not change. the format of **date same as 22/08/2013** there is **no change to 2013/08/22**

How to change the format dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd in scala

Comment: You may want to have look on date formatter tutorial .. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Modern comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string). This could be relevant too? [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a `SimpleDateFormat` which first parses your string and get `Date` from it. And then convert it to whatever format.

```
 var s:String ="22/08/2013"
 var  simpleDateFormat:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
 var  date:Date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
 val ans = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd").format(date) 
 println(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this it works for me.

```
val s: String = "22/08/2013"
val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy")
val date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s)
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd")
println(df.format(date))
```

Comment: i need df as util date how to do that,.,

Comment: sorry, i don't know of a standard utility function which can convert between formats. will have to write custom helper functions.

Comment: @zzztimbo why do you think so. If you see the time of answering, we both answered in 1 min difference. Also i did not copy paste the other answer. If you observe closely, I have followed the Scala convention of using `val`s instead of `var`s

Comment: @user007 I apologize, I didn't notice the vals. Using vars is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle error in John Vishal's answer:
mm defines 08 as minutes, not as month. Use MM instead.

Corrected code:

```
val s = "2013_08_14"
val simpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd")
val date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s)
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
println(df.format(date))
```

Comment: Correct, even both of the other answers have that error. We shouldn’t waste our time on `SimpleDateFormat` anyway, though. It’s a notoriously troublesome class and long outdated.