# fmt:formatDate error jsp

Tags: jsp, formatdatetime

i used formatdate as follow

```
<p>Formatted Date (4): <fmt:formatDate type="both"  dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" value="${eventDetailList.activityTime}" /></p>
```

but not working,don't display anything in all page
but this work

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<p>Formatted Date (4): <fmt:formatDate type="both"  dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" value="${now}" /></p>
```

i want to get time this format `23/09/16 14:27`

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format

Comment: On the above link try to put like this : `sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm");`. That is what your format look like

Comment: What does _not working_ mean? Does it cause an error / exception? Does it display nothing? Does it display the date/time in wrong format?

Comment: nothing show any one of the browser