# converting string date to sql Date format in java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I would like to achieve below:

I have date in string format as e.g. "2015-05-12 15:15:24", 
I would like to convert it to sql date in the format "dd-MMM-yy". 
However, this is not working. below is the code snippet:

```
    String rawDate="2015-05-12 15:15:24";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date =format.parse(rawDate);
    Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat changedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date date2=changedFormat.parse(changedFormat.format(sqlDate));
    Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime());

    System.out.println("sqlDate : "+sqlDate +"  ::::::   Date2 : "+date2+"  :::: sqlDate2  "+sqlDate2);ow here is the Test : "+sqlDate2);
```

The output of the program is :

sqlDate : 2015-05-12  ::::::   Date2 : Tue May 12 00:00:00 BST 2015  :::: sqlDate2  2015-05-12

The aim was to get date in the format of 12-May-15 java.sql format, but May is not being translated into alphabet month rather its printed as number.

am I missing anything. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The challenge is that I need to use java.sql.Date in setDate method and it takes java.sql.date as second parameter i.e.   setDate(java.lang.String sCol,  
                    java.sql.Date d)

Comment: The `java.sql.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the `java.time.LocalDate` class. Use `PreparedStatement::setObject` to pass the `LocalDate`.

Comment: See similar Question, [*Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43039614/642706).

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You want to convert a string to a SQL date, that is OK and not hard to do. But then you go on to say "SQL date **in the format <whatever>**". In SQL (and in most languages, really) DATE is not a string data type, and in particular it doesn't have a format. What is your actual question - do you need to take a string (which is supposed to represent a date in a certain format) and convert it to a different **string**, representing the same date but in a different format?

Comment: @mathguy is right. The outdated `java.sql.Date` type always prints in yyyy-MM-dd format, but this doesn’t mean that it *has* this format ’cause it’s got no format at all, and your `PreparedStatement` is happy to take it regardless. Basil Bourque is right too, though, you should certainly prefer `LocalDate` and like `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(4, yourLocalDate)`. About a date in a format see also [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use objects, not strings, to communicate with database.

Use only *java.time* classes, never `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, or `java.sql.Date` classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(                      // Use smart objects, not dumb strings.
    … ,                                             // Specify which placeholder `?` in you SQL.
    LocalDateTime.parse(                            // Parse input string lacking any zone or offset as a `LocalDateTime` object. *NOT* a moment, just a vague idea about *potential* moments.
        "2015-05-12 15:15:24".replace( " " , "T" )  // Alter your input string to comply with ISO 8601 standard format, with `T` in the middle.
    )                                               // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
    .atOffset(                                      // Apply an offset-from-UTC to determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
        ZoneOffset.UTC                              // Apply UTC if the input string was intended to be a moment in UTC.
    )                                               // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
    .toLocalDate()                                  // Extract a date-only value, a `LocalDate` object from the date-with-time `OffsetDateTime` object.
)
```

## Details

> convert it to sql date in the format "dd-MMM-yy"

There is no such SQL-standard format. SQL-standard format for a date is the same as ISO 8601 standard format: YYYY-MM-DD.

## java.time

You are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

The *java.time* classes use standard ISO 8601 format by default when parsing and generating strings. Your input string is nearly compliant with the standard. Just replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input =  "2015-05-12 15:15:24".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment. It represents *potential* moments along a span of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe. If you know the intended time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. If you know only a mere offset rather than a zone, apply a `ZoneOffset` to get a `OffsetDateTime` object. I will assume your value is intended to represent a moment in UTC, in other words, an offset-from-UTC of zero.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( Offset.UTC ) ;
```

### Smart objects, not dumb strings

You should use class types appropriate to your SQL data types to exchange data with your database. Use smart objects, not dumb strings.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

You care only about the date, not the time-of-day. So extract a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Submit to your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myPreparedStatement.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## Complete example

Here is a complete example app, in a single `.java`.

Using the [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/html/main.html). We specify an in-memory database, never persisted to storage, as this is just a demo.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DateIntoDatabase {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        DateIntoDatabase app = new DateIntoDatabase();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:date_into_db_example_" ) ;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ (\n" +
            "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
            "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,\n" +
            "  when_ DATE NOT NULL\n" +
            ") ; ";
            System.out.println( sql );
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , when_ ) " + "VALUES ( ? , ? ) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
                String name = "whatever";
                LocalDate ld = LocalDateTime.parse( "2015-05-12 15:15:24".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate();

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ld );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = ( UUID ) rs.getObject( "id_" );  // Cast the `Object` object to UUID if your driver does not support JDBC 4.2 and its ability to pass the expected return type for type-safety.
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( "when_" , LocalDate.class );

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println( "id: " + id + " | name: " + name + " | when: " + ld );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

> id: 0a4fd38c-7d4e-4049-bc21-e349582c8bc5 | name: whatever | when: 2015-05-12

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: setObject method has done the tick.. thanks for your help :) and the detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

You computed it, but never printed it:

```
String rawDate = "2015-05-12 15:15:24";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(rawDate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat changedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + changedFormat.format(sqlDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, however I want the date in sql date format, this returns the desired date in String format

Comment: What do you mean by "In SQL date format"? Please elaborate. The `java.sql.Date` class represents a Date (without time) but does not -- I repeat -- does not include any formatting of the date. That's the job of a formatter.

Comment: I specified the format in SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); but this doesn't seem to take effect. as the month is printed as number(i.e. 05) instead of alphabet(i.e. May), what I want to achieve is that it return the date in format e.g. 12-May-18 in java sql date variable.

Comment: @RashidKhan - you seem terribly confused between "data type" and "format". DATE and STRING are data types, there is no such thing as "date format" and "string format". And a date does not have a format; "format" applies **only** to the string representations of dates, not to the dates themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have in your code the date in the format you want, but you are assing into a other object type date .

change this :

```
Date date2=changedFormat.parse(changedFormat.format(sqlDate));
Date sqlDate2 = new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime());
```

to this :  `String dateformat =(changedFormat.format(sqlDate));`

you can pass the value from the string yo your object date. but if you print the var date you don´t print in the format you want, and this is becouse :

**Date does not store any format into itself.**

Comment: Thanks, Can I pass the exact calculated date in java sql date variable?

Comment: Yes you can pass, but if you print the sql date var , you will print in the format "dd-MM-yy" not "dd-MMM-yy"