# Android format Date and return Date as dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: android, java.util.date, formatdatetime

How can I format a `Date String` to pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy` and return the value as a `date`.?

I've used `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(date)` but the return value is like `Sun Oct 07 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2018` but I need it like `07-Oct-2018`

Any easy way to format and return as a `date` to `dd-MMM-yyyy` pattern.?

Comment: Look at the first output of [this](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-format-a-date-into-ddmmyyyy/) example. The other examples are for different kinds of formatting.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(date)`

Comment: @miguelarc, @m0skit0 They are returning `String` not `Date` I need the return type as `Date`

Comment: Date obj does not have a format. You get a formatted date only when you convert it to string.

Comment: @AmEénÁhsAn Ok. Why I'm getting two different type of date format like
`Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 BDT 2018` and
`Sun Oct 07 00:00:00 GMT+06:00 2018`

Comment: You are mixing things. The output that you are seeing is the full structure representation of the class [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). You can't simply convert the output of a class ot what you desire. However, you can use the `Date.get()` method to build the string that you desire. You can do something like `String date = Date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString() + Date.get(Calendar.MONTH).toString() + Date.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString()`

Comment: Possibly (more precisely) duplicate of [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DateFormat.parse(String), that will return a new Date object. For more information [DateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))