# dateParser returns not expeted result?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have DateAdapter for JPA date field:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS z");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try unmarshal String:

> 19990102T025555.000 GMT

unmarshal method returns

> Sat Jan 02 05:55:55 MSK 1999

But I need return the same thing, which saved in base.

Comment: A `Date` value doesn't know about a time zone. If you need to be able to store different time zones, you'll need to use a different type.

Comment: You should not use `Date` class which is deprecated for a while

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). While `Date` is not officially deprecated, it is certainly long outdated, so you should treat it as though it were.

Comment: The code you already have *does* save the correct date and time to the database. However, a modern JPA implementation will accept one of `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant` for persisting and will also give you the same type back, so there’s no need for you to use the poorly designed and long outdated `java.util.Date` class at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format)

Comment: As an aside, your format is a peculiar mix of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and something that isn’t ISO 8601, and I am in severe doubt whether it’s got any good use. Internally in your program you should use date-time objects, not strings. For presentation to the user, I think that they will be happier with a localized format like for example `14 дек. 2018 г., 13:09:45 Москва, стандартное время`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able and willing to replace `Date` with `ZonedDateTime` (from Java 8), you can do this:

```
private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS z");

ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("19990102T025555.000 GMT", dateFormat);
System.out.println(date);                    // 1999-01-02T02:55:55Z[GMT]
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); // 19990102T025555.000 GMT
```