# Java 8 Output date as YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, date, getter

I have a getter in Java 8 that I set to the below, problem is the output is `Sat Jan 11 00:00:00 AEDT 2020`

The class has to remain as a `Date`, `StartDate` is a `LocalDate`.

```
public static Date getStartDate() {
    return Date.from(StartDate.atStartOfDay()
                      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                      .toInstant());
}
```

I need it to return the value as `YYYY-MM-DD` and I am struggling to work it out.

Yes, this is an assignment. No idea on the logic where we've been told to set one to `Date` and the other as `LocalDate`, other than to annoy me......

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you have to return `YYYY-MM-DD`, then you're expected to return a `String`. Does your assignment say you must return `java.util.Date`?

Comment: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` cannot have a format. See for example [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format).

Comment: The simple `StartDate.toString()` will give you a string in the format you asked for.But a `String`, not a `Date`. The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated anyway, so you may consider living with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Straightforward Answer - SimpleDateFormatter

As you state that the type returned by `getStartDate` must remain a `Date`. In this case, the most straightforward way to do this is to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class:

You can pass the date into a [`SimpleDateFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```java
SimpleDateFormat iso_8601_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(iso_8601_formatter.format(getStartDate());
```

More detailed information can be found at [this](https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format) blog post.

## Best Practice Answer - Use `java.time`

As noted by Ole V.V., if it becomes possible to refactor the code, it would be best to unify the codebase around `java.time` instead of mixing that API with `java.util.Date`. This can be accomplished with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```java
DateTimeFormatter iso_8601_formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate start = StartDate.atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(start.format(iso_8601_formatter));
```

Note that DateTimeFormatter supplies the constant [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) for printing values in ISO-8601 format.

More information about the improvements made in the new API can be found in [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) article.

Comment: @user10631180 you are actually accepted an answer, which is duplicate of another one, posted earlier. I recommend you to take a look at another, since it is more readable (which is essential in production). You should not build long callback chains like `println(simpleDateFormat.format(getStartDate());`

Comment: Excuse me if my comment looks harsh, I just wanted to add an advice to the answer

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @Ole V. V.
The question specifically stated that the class had to remain a Date. However, I have updated my post to recommend that the swtich be made where possible.

Comment: @Steyrix
We have a difference of opinion here. I have worked with multiple projects where reading code is difficult due to the amount of vertical space it takes up - jumping back and forth through the file becomes cumbersome. In this particular example, the variable names don't add much value (in fact, the name `date` is misleading since it appears to specify a type). Having 1 variable is a reasonable tradeoff between the complexity of the line and the amount of vertical space the code takes.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this solution.

```
public static String getStartDate() {
    DateTimeFormatter oldPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
    DateTimeFormatter newPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(new Date().toInstant().toString(), oldPattern);
    return datetime.format(newPattern);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this to get the date value as "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Doesn't matter, It gives flexibility and work in both cases. You can check it !

Comment: It definitely matters: for example printing 2019-12-31 using YYYY when in - for example - The Netherlands, will print 2020, because YYYY is the week-year, not the calendar-year, and 2019-12-31 falls in week 1-2020. And printing that date with DD will result in 365, because DD is the day-in-year, not the day-in-month. So printing 2019-12-31 using YYYY-MM-DD prints 2020-12-365, while yyyy-MM-dd results in the correct 2019-12-31.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: OK, I will keep that in mind, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

While returning an instance of `java.util.Date`, you cannot format it. It will always be returned as a Date object. In case you want it in string,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

where `new Date()` is todays date, whatever date object you put, the sdf object (`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) will do that.
You can refer to [java 8 docs of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more.