# Date without time doesn't hide seconds

Tags: java, date, seconds

I'm using `Joda Time` to remove seconds from a date.

Firstly, I have this kind of `Date`:

```
Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2020
```

I pick this date from a local db using this method:

```
public static Date dateTimeFromString(String s) {

    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    Date d= null;
    try {
        d = sdf.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
```

From this date I would reach a form like this:

```
Thu Nov 05 CET 2020
```

or even better like this:`Thu Nov 05 2020`.

Now, I'm trying to use this method from `Joda Time:`

```
private Date dateWitoutTime(Date date){
    return new LocalDate(date).toDate();
}
```

but still getting

```
Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2020
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Your method is returning a `Date`. The output appears to be the `.toString()` of the `Date`. A `Date` includes time. Do you really want to return a `Date` or a `String` from `dateWithoutTime(...)`?

Comment: I want a `String`, but I don't want the `HH:mm:ss`. I used that method because It is from `Joda Time`

Comment: There is no point in removing the time by turning it into a LocalDate and then turning into a Date again since Date always includes time even if its 00:00. You either keep the LocalDate object and work with that or you specify the desired format when printing out the Date object

Comment: Does this somehow answer your question? [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not contaminate the clean `java.time` API with the legacy error-prone `java.util` date-time API. You can do it as follows using the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)));
        System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)));

        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime givenDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2020", dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(givenDateTime.format(dtfOutput));
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
04-Nov-2020 17:13
Wed Nov 04 2020
Thu Nov 05 CET 2020
Wed Nov 04 CET 2020
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now));
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now));

        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date givenDateTime = sdfInput.parse("Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2020");

        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdfOutput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(givenDateTime));
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(now));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
04-Nov-2020 17:13
Wed Nov 04 2020
Thu Nov 05 CET 2020
Wed Nov 04 CET 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java8+, there's no need for JodaTime.

A `Date` instance includes the time; there's no getting around that. Maybe you want to return a `String` instead.

```java
    // Pre-Java8
    private String dateWithoutTime(final Date date) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d yyyy");
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

    // Java8+
    private String dateWithoutTime(final LocalDate date) {
        final DateTimeFormat formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy");
        return date.format(formatter);
    }

    private String dateWithoutTime(final Date date) {
        final LocalDate localDate = convertDateToLocalDate(date);
        return dateWithoutTime(localDate);
    }

    private LocalDate convertDateToLocalDate(final Date date) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Only please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Yje OP is already using Joda-Time, which is far superior (Java 8+ or not). Joda-Time includes classes `DateTimeFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting dates, so I recommend that you use those instead. Or even better, move on to java.time and it `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that Joda-Time is superior if you're already using Java8.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I’m perfectly fine with the disagreement and very curious about your opinion. I said that Joda-Time was superior *to `SimpleDateFormat`*. Did you misunderstand that? Or do you think that `SimpleDateFormat` has been considerably improved from Java 7 to Java 8, and if so, how? Also thanks for your edit, I consider it a good improvement.

Comment: I did not read you original statement as "Joda-Time is superior to `SimpleDateFormat`"; I took it as saying it should be used even when `java.time` is available. Thanks for the response and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a `String`, …

Well, there’s something wrong about converting from one string format to another string format. Just as you keep numbers in `int` variables and Boolean values in `boolean` variables (I hope), you should keep dates in `LocalDate` variables, either the `LocalDate` class from Joda-Time or the one from java.time, the modern Java date and time API that has supplanted Joda-Time. But since you ask, then have your method return a `String`:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

public static String dateTimeFromString(String s) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s);
    return date.toString(dateFormatter);
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(dateTimeFromString("2020-11-05"));
```

Output:

> Thu Nov 05 2020

I have specified a locale for the formatter to make sure that the abbreviations printed are in English.

You cannot have a `Date` nor a `LocalDate` that prints as `Thu Nov 05 2020`. The `toString` methods of those classes are defined to print a specific format. You can have the format of your choice only in a `String`. And that’s good: it helps keeping your model and your presentation separate.