# Convert a date to another format date using LocalDate

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, localdate, datetimeformatter

Can I know how can convert one date format  to another date format.

```
public static LocalDate localDateToAnotherLocalDate(String oldPattern, String newPattern, String input) {
    DateTimeFormatter oldFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(oldPattern);
    DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(newPattern);
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, oldFormat);
    String output = localDate.format(newFormat);
    System.out.println();
    return getLocalDate(output, newPattern);
}

public static LocalDate getLocalDate(String date, String datePattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
    return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

}

@Test
void getLocalDateToAnotherLocalDateTest() {
    LocalDate localDate = DateUtil.localDateToAnotherLocalDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy", "2022-11-20");
    System.out.println("localDate" + localDate.toString());
    assertEquals("20-11-2022", localDate.toString());
}
```

Comment: @geocodezip    I do not want the date in the format of string. I need back as Local date in different format

Comment: @bharathi The link provided by geocodezip does answer your question.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash what is wrong with the code you provided in the question? At first glance it is a working code that does what you want. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @MichaelGantman - It's not my question. 

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Oops. Sorry. Bharathi Please look at my previous comment

Comment: You cannot. You also should not want to. More details in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485250/5772882). In that answer I am using the old-fashioned `Date` as example, but what I say is just as true of `LocalDate`, which I also state at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A LocalDate object can only ever be printed in ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd). In order to print the object in some other format, you need to format it and save the LocalDate as a string.